# How to recognise geometric symmetry in a formula

Tags: geometry, self-learning

#### Background

In a question I'm working on (course problem set for a Mathematics BSc, second year module in mechanics and fluids, unpublished), we're given a problem involving the surface

\begin{align}
z
& = \frac{1}{a^2}(4a^2-x^2-y^2)^\frac{3}{2} \\
& = \frac{1}{a^2}(4a^2-r^2)^\frac{3}{2}
\end{align}

and, looking at the solution booklet, we're expected to recognise that this is symmetrical about the $z$-axis and use that fact in the solution.

Having put the formula into geogebra, I now know the shape is a downward-opening paraboloid*, and might recognise the formula in future. If I look at the formula, I can sort of see why it should be symmetric.

**Edit:** * Henry tells me this is wrong.

#### Question

Is there a way of expressing what it is about this formula that is sufficient to show symmetry? e.g. "$z$ is a polynomial in $r$, therefore the shape is symmetrical about the $z$-axis".

Comment: If $z$ can be expressed as a function of $x^2$ and $y^2$ with no other $x$ or $y$ terms then there is reflexive symmetry. If $z$ can be expressed purely as a function of $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ with no $\theta$ or other $x$ or $y$ terms, then it is full rotational symmetry about the $z$-axis.    It may look like a paraboloid but thanks to the $\frac32$ exponent, it is not one

Comment: @Henry Thanks, that's what I was looking for. If you care to post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Request from comments:*

- If $z$ can be expressed as a function of $x^2$ and $y^2$ with no other $x$ or $y$ terms then there is reflection symmetry.
- If $z$ can be expressed purely as a function of $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ with no $\theta$ or other $x$ or $y$ terms, then it is fully rotationally symmetry about the $z$-axis.
- It may look like a paraboloid but thanks to the $\frac32$ exponent, it is not one